# How to edit starting parameters of the genesis block in mix?

Tags: mix, blocks, genesis

When I click the "import" button it seems to want to import stuff from a file. But what structure etc should the file have?

Cannot find any documentation on this. Any pointers gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature involves AlethZero. 
There's an option in AZ to export the state which can be imported in Mix using this feature.